# Factory Boy vs. custom objects

Tags: python, django, tdd, django-testing, factory-boy

The question:

**What are the advantages of using Factory Boy in the following situation? I don't really see why I shouldn't just deliver my own custom objects. If I am wrong please show me why.**

I am using Factory Boy to make user instances during my tests, which creates a UserProfile object dynamically (standard recipe from Factory_Boy [documentation](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/recipes.html)).

The Data class creates data that will be delivered to forms during a post (other methods I'm using deliver data for self.client.post methods that login, register, and activate users. Unless I'm missing something, I'd have to build a separate DjangoModelFactory subclass for each situation in order to use ClassName.attributes() where the data requirements differ. The other reason I went in this direction is that UserProfile has a User foreign key, so I wasn't able to call UserProfileFactory.attributes() directly, only UserFactory.attributes(). Why not just make my own like I'm doing?

```
#Factories.py

IMAGE_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 
                          '../../test_files/test_images/image.jpeg')
class UserProfileFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = UserProfile

    user = factory.SubFactory('portal.factories.UserFactory', profile=None)

    first_name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "Joe_%d" % n)
    last_name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "Schmoe_%d" % n)
    nickname = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "JoeBlow_%d" % n)
    profile_image = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda t: File(open(IMAGE_PATH)))


class UserFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = User

    username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "user_%d" % n)
    password = make_password("password")
    email = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "user_%d@gmail.com" % n)

    profile = factory.RelatedFactory(UserProfileFactory, 'user')

    @classmethod
    def _generate(cls, create, attrs):
        models.signals.post_save.disconnect(user_post_save, sender=User)
        user = super(UserFactory, cls)._generate(create, attrs)
        models.signals.post_save.connect(user_post_save, sender=User)
        return user


class Data(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.IMAGE_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 
                                       '../../test_files/test_images/image.jpeg')
        self.profile_image = File(open(IMAGE_PATH))

    def get_profile_update(self, user):
        return {'first_name': 'Jeff',
                'last_name': 'Lebowski',
                'nickname': 'The Dude',
                'profile_image': self.profile_image,
                'user': user.pk,}

    def and_so_on(self):
        continues...
```

Then I am using data like this in the following context during my integration tests:

```
class PortalTestCase(TestCase):
    """Shortened and simplified"""
    def test_edit_profile_post(self):
        user = UserFactory.create()
        login_bool = self.client.login(username=user.username,
                                       password=self.data.get_password())
        data = self.data.get_profile_update(user)
        response = self.client.post(reverse(self.get_edit_profile()),
                                data=data, 
                                follow=True)
        success_url = 'http://testserver%s' % reverse(self.get_portal())
        template_name = self.get_portal_template()
        content_text_img = 'src="/' + user.get_profile().profile_image.url + '"'
        self.assertRedirects(response, success_url)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, template_name)
        self.assertContains(response, content_text_img)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that in this single instance test case factory boy may be overkill.  However think about the application as whole.  More often than not you will need to use another UserFactory object.  Guess what that footwork has already been done. The reason I choose to use factory boy is consistent reusability.

As the [documentation](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html) lays out but doesn't exactly spell out this tool is meant to grow with your application and not replace a single isolated tescase.